# Which NSView does Finder use to show files?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to show all the files in a folder as shown below(image):
[image]

Also, I would be really thank full if you could give me link of some tutorials to study the very view and how to use it.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [`NSBrowser`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBrowser_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSBrowser). Read Apple's [Browser Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Browser/Browser.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000018i) for even more info. I think their browser may be customized to get the full behavior seen in the Finder.